# Accessing elements Linestring and points from a DGN file and displaying both layers on QgsMapCanvas

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, dgn

I am using PyQGIS APIs to develop a standalone application which currently display's map data layers on QgsMapCanvas from .shp, .tif, .dgn files.
I am able to do it for .shp and .tif but not for  .dgn
Basically, my .dgn file contains some cities marked as points and some boundaries when i import the .dgn file in **QGIS** it asks me to select two elements, that are- LineStrings(boundaries) and Points(cities)
.dgn file when opened in **my standalone application** can only load one element i.e the boundaries(Linestrings).
How can i resolve this issue programatically using PyQGIS? Also, what type of format is .dgn raster or vector(I know it's a CAD file but it oughta' be one of raster/vector too).